# Internet through 3 routers and one PC sharing internet

Tags: networking, routing, home-networking, internet-connection, wireless-access-point

due to coronavirus I can't go out and order access points and stuff like that, so I'm trying to figure out a solution with what I have at the moment.

my situation is the following:

I have a router A that has DHCP enabled and is connected to the ADSL (ip 192.168.1.1)

I have a router B (ip 192.168.0.1) that is connected via cable to the router A with DHCP disable. All devices connected via wireless to A or B can go to internet without problems. In both cases, I use 192.168.1.1 as default gateway.

Problem is that downstairs there is signal only in a room and I'd like the connection to reach also the other ones. I have both a router and an old computer that I can use to help me in this task.

Apparently it's not possible to use this old router as access point. It can be used only if I set a low level of security encryption and if I had another router of the same family... I've tried this configuration instead:

I've connected a computer to this old router (let's call it router C that has ip 192.168.1.2) through ethernet (I've tried both in the single internet port and one of the other 4) and I've connected this computer also to the wireless network of router B. On windows I've tried to share the connection of the adapter connected to router B, and I've tried to set different addresses both in the router C and in the different computers I have here. In the router C there is an option where I can set gateway address, but it seems that whatever address I set, I can't get internet in the other rooms. I can also use Linux, but I think the real problem is how to setup the ip addresses in a correct way.

Any hint?

Comment: This part seems off: _"It can be used only if I set a low level of security encryption and if I had another router of the same family.."_ – it sounds very much like you tried to configure it as a _repeater_, not an access point! Wired access points will never have such restrictions, but the (obsolete) single-radio wireless repeater mode certainly does.

Comment: thank you for your reply. it was the only option I could see that was related to "network sharing" I could see in the router.. it's an old router indeed

Comment: Well, you don't really need special options... wireless routers _already do_ everything that's necessary for this. Most of the time, you only need to disable or bypass router-specific features that are _unnecessary_ for a "pure" access point, such as DHCP service or indeed the actual "routing".

Comment: so you're suggesting that I don't really need that Windows machine?